# How to use Firebase notification with .net maui

Tags: .net, firebase, notifications, maui

This is my first use of Firebase. If possible, I want a way on how to use the firebasse notification, and I use .net maui

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin -> Plugin.Firebase